# One model, one table different user types and different controllers, how to handle policies?

Tags: laravel, policies

I have one model `user` and one table against that model `users` I have different roles for user as patient, hospital and so on, each user have different fields and values to enter during registration so I have created different `routes` and `controllers` for different roles.

Now I'm facing problem during `authorization` process how I can authorize. I have only one model `user` so I can create only one `policy` called `UserPolicy` and use the `$this->authorize` method in the `UserController`.

I have also other controllers as `PatientController`, `HospitalController` which all bound to the one table and model called `user` and fetching the record only based on the user type. **Now how can I create the policies for them and use the `$this->authorize` method in the Hospital, Patient controllers?**

Answer (score 1):

you are using the same table and you require different data from each kind if user ?
anyway if that the situation , you can create a type field in the users table , then create 2 middlewares , in your middleware check the type of the user then throw an exception or make him pass